# Array index out of bounds

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

I know there are a few posts regarding this particular error but none of the answers to those posts seem to fix my problem. Basically I am reading a txt file into the arraylist listS. It compiles without error, but when I run it, I get "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2". Apparently the problem is in line 359 which is "double tempArea = Double.parseDouble(tokenize[2]);". I cannot see anything wrong with that line and so I also checked for extra braces or semicolons but found none. I have included my code below. Can anyone see what the cause of the error might be?

```
 ArrayList<String>listS = new ArrayList<>();


    try
    {
      BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("EssentialsSaleFile.txt"));
      String fileRead = bR.readLine();
      while(fileRead != null)
      {
                String[] tokenize = fileRead.split(",");
                String tempType = tokenize[0];
                String tempAddress = tokenize[1];
                double tempArea = Double.parseDouble(tokenize[2]);
                int tempNumOfBedrooms = Integer.parseInt(tokenize[3]);
                int tempNumOfToilets = Integer.parseInt(tokenize[4]);
                int tempNumOfGarages = Integer.parseInt(tokenize[5]);
                String tempSellerName = tokenize[6];
                String tempSellerPhone = tokenize[7];
                String tempSaleOfferDate = tokenize[8];
                String tempSaleOfferEndDate = tokenize[9];
                double tempAskingAmount = Double.parseDouble(tokenize[10]);
                String tempAssignedEmployee = tokenize[11];
                double tempSalesCommissionPerc = Double.parseDouble(tokenize[12]);

                String tempObj = new String();

                listS.add(tempObj);
                fileRead = bR.readLine();


      }



                bR.close();

    }





        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File not here.");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Um, a line in your text file that only has two elements in? Hint: try logging the line you're splitting before you do the split...

Comment: *Obviously* `tokenize` only contains 2 elements. That is what the error message tells you, that is what you have to look into, set a breakpoint before the line and inspect `tokenize` and `fileRead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the code itself.
The `tokensize` array contains as many elements as there are comma seperated strings in you line.

Since the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when accessing the 3rd element (`tokenize[2]`) there is a line with only one comma in your file.

For example:
The line `foo,bar` gives you the array `["foo","bar"]` which only has two elements. Accessing `tokenize[2]` will result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple. There's a line in your file that contains exactly one comma. Splitting this line by commas returns an array with only two elements, which makes accessing tokenize[2] out of bounds.

First of all you should check what the line that was examined contains.
After that, add a check after the split if the length of tokenize is 13 and if not, skip the line or some other appropriate action, like showing a message or logging the line.